# I installed Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2015 but it's not found

Tags: c#, oracle, crystal-reports

I click on add item in the solution explorer to add Crystal Report but there's no reports/reporting section found... what should I do??

Comment: It happened to me once. Running the install as administrator did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue and resolved it following steps below:

- Select your project in the solution explorer window
- Right click and select properties on the project
- A new tab should open that starts on the Application Tab, you should
  see 
       Target Framework drop down...its in the 3rd row from the top.
      Change your Target framework there...It should pre-populate with .net 
     framework 4 client profile...change it to just .net Framework 4 and then hit 
     ctrl + s or make sure you save your changes.